Webhook is not working in HealthChecksUI in .NET Core 6
"HealthChecksUI": {
  "HealthChecks": [
    {
      "Name": "My Health Checks",
      "Uri": "/health"
    }
  ],
  "Webhooks": [
    {
      "name": "healthcheckapi",
      "uri": "https://localhost:44365/WeatherForecast",
      "payload": "{ \"message\": \"Webhook report for [[LIVENESS]]: [[FAILURE]] - Description: [[DESCRIPTIONS]]\"}",
      "restorePayload": "{ \"message\": \"[[LIVENESS]] is back to life\"}"
    }
  ],
  "EvaluationTimeInSeconds" : 5
}

I want to get call from healthcheck when status is unhealthy and send another call when it is healthy.

now payload working on fail but why restorePayload is not working?

Do you get any error message ?

no it only call the payload when status is unhealthy but after status healthy it don't call the api or webhook
